# Messagepack Serializer for C# also ok to use with VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, msgpack, messagepack-csharp

I have started using the [Messagepack Serializer for C#](https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp) with VB.NET because it is very fast but mostly because it is well-maintained with frequent releases.

It works well with VB.NET and haven't run in to any issues yet, but I wonder if there are issues that can be expected with VB.NET as it is so specifically called Messagepack Serializer for C# not Messagepack Serializer for .NET.

Thank you for sharing your insights!

Comment: You can seamlessly mix VB.NET and C#. You can have a Solution that has Projects written in both languages. You can of course use Packages **written** in C#, hence created for .NET

Comment: In most cases, I would expect anything written for .NET (regardless of whether it is specifically marketed as being for C#) to work with VB.  The only exceptions would be new .NET features that don't have VB support; I don't remember right now exactly what they are, but I vaguely recall something like ref returns and something memory-buffer-related like spans.  For the most part, I think you would run into compile-time failures if you hit anything like that.

Comment: There are also a few .NET features which VB has that C# does not, like indexer properties.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Agreed, but not particular relevant to the question of whether one can use a library developed for / tested against C# from VB.  It would be more relevant for the reverse (where indexer properties can be used from C# but it's a bit of a PITA because you have to revert to direct calls to the getter and setter).